# how to reduce in multiple try catch

Tags: asp.net

hi i am beginner to develop a project, in my project i used try catch with in try catch so how i write the query professionally...

my code is....

```
try
    {
        //connection();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        txtcusname.Text = "";
        txtcusnumber.Text = "";
        query = "sample_SP";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetCusID", txtcusid.Text).ToString();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GrdCustomerDetails.DataSource = ds;
        GrdCustomerDetails.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        try
        {
            //connection();
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            ViewState["VSCusID"] = txtcusid.Text;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select contname,mob from CustContacts_TB where cid='" + ViewState["VSCusID"] + " '", con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            txtcusname.Text = dr["contname"].ToString();
            txtcusnumber.Text=dr["mob"].ToString();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            //connection();
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            ViewState["VSCusID"] = txtcusid.Text;
            //cmd = new SqlCommand("select compname from CustCreate_TB inner join CustContacts_TB on CustContacts_TB.'" + ViewState["VSCusID"] + "'=CustCreate_TB.'" + ViewState["VSCusID"] + "' ", con);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select compname from CustCreate_TB where cid='" + ViewState["VSCusID"] + " ' ", con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            txtcompname.Text = dr["compname"].ToString();
            con.Close();
            //txtcusname.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 

    }
    finally
    {
        //connection();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select compliantID,priorty,status from NewComp1 where customerid='" + ViewState["VSCusID"] + "' and status='open'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        grdpending.DataSource = ds;
        grdpending.DataBind();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select compliantID,priorty,status from NewComp1 where customerid='" + ViewState["VSCusID"] + "' and status='closed'", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        grdClosed.DataSource = ds;
        grdClosed.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

it possible to reduce code and it correct format.... thank you for helping and its useful to develop my coding skills

Comment: It's very easy - get rid of all the try/catch blocks. You don't understand what exception handling is about

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have:

```
try
    {        
        [block1]
        try
        {
            [block2]
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            [block3]
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 

    }
    finally
    {
        [block4]
    }
  }
```

They all seem to fetch data and populate controls or variables. You haven't specified what you would do in an exception, so you could simply have them all in a single try block, or put them all in individual blocks. I can't see why they have to be nested.
`Finally` is usually used for 'clean up' operations, like disposing of open connections but you seem to be using your `Finally` for a new select & populate operation, which is wrong.

so:

```
try
    {        
        [block1]
        [block2]
        [block3]
        [block4]      
  }
```

or if you needed to know when a specific block had failed but each in try/catch

```
try
  {        
        [block1]                 
  }
  ...
try
  {        
        [block4]                 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you making all this connection =???

you may do it

```
try {
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cnn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()) {
    if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        cnn.Open();
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()) {
        //first task
    }
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()) {
        //second one
    }
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cdm2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()) {
        //third task
    }

}
} catch (SqlClient.SqlException sqlex) {
//catch exception sql
//to do
} catch (Exception ex) {
//generic exceptio
//to do some stuff
} finally {
//if need to do later
}
```